# "Call in sick" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases

> I always drank until past midnight, and there we'd sit, at 5 a.m. in the morning, waiting to get on the clock, waiting for some regular to call in sick.

In here what does "to call in sick"  mean

Comment: Have you tried looking it  up? "Call in sick"?

Comment: Please pay attention to the formatting of your questions next time you post. The formatting tools at the top of the text box are easy to learn. Make use of block-quotes, parentheses, and boldface/italics. Also this question is general reference, and can be answered by simply looking up the phrase on Google.

Comment: In the cambridge dictionary,  if you call in sick,  you phone to say that you are unable to work because of illness. And next sentence is like that "The regulars usually called in sick when it rained or during a heatwave or the day after a holiday when the mail load was doubled"  in this context it is difficult to understand meaning

Comment: That's easy. They lied to avoid going to work. "I don't want to." won't get you very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Call in sick](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+in+sick)*** or ***[report in sick](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/report+in+sick)*** are expressions meaning:

> To inform one's employer that one will be absent due to illness (real or feigned).
>
> The phrase originally referred to calling by phone, but can refer to any form of communication (such as email).
>
> - *That virus has totally decimated my staff—only two people are in the office today because the rest called in sick! If you really want to go to the beach tomorrow, just call in sick.*

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

It simply means "to telephone your workplace to tell them that you are sick and won't be coming to work".

> Employees should call in sick before 7 am.